# Mono-complete 5.0.1.1 installed - but executes 3.2.7

Tags: apt, mono

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system - which seems to have mono 3 installed by default. As I needed to run software which requires a more recent version, I followed the guide [here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin) and installed the project repo and upgraded.

Now when I check the version for the mono-complete package (and mono-runtime) I get back the following, which entirely makes sense to me:

```
mono-complete:
  Installed: 5.0.1.1-0xamarin5+ubuntu1404b1
  Candidate: 5.0.1.1-0xamarin5+ubuntu1404b1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.1.1-0xamarin5+ubuntu1404b1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.2.3.4-0xamarin2 0
        500 http://apt.sonarr.tv/ master/main amd64 Packages
     4.2.1.102-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://apt.sonarr.tv/ master/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

However running the actual 'mono' program or checking the version of it shows the old version, preventing me from running the software:

```
mono -V
Mono Runtime Engine version 3.2.7 (master/0a558a7 Fri Jan  3 18:26:01 GMT 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2013 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen'
```

Any idea how I can get it to use the right version?

Comment: Close the terminal and open another and try it again!

Comment: I've restarted the system a number of times with no difference - I'm accesssing the terminal via SSH but I don't think that should make a difference?

Comment: Since version 3.2.**7** doesn't appear anywhere in the apt policy output, perhaps it is something that was installed outside the package system, and its binary happens to be in a location that's earlier in your `PATH`? Have you checked `which mono` and/or `type mono`?

Comment: $ which mono provides a path of /usr/local/bin/mono which then returns 3.2.7 - so it seems like I've ended up with multiple installations of mono? How do I check the PATH?

Comment: You can use `echo $PATH` - however it almost certainly has `/usr/local` ahead of wherever mono 5.0.1.1 is installed (likely `/usr/bin`), which explains the behaviour you are seeing. Probably the simplest thing to do is rename `/usr/local/bin/mono` to `/usr/local/bin/mono.old` or somesuch.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, found the 'real' mono in /usr/bin and used it successfully

Answer (score 0):

Mono v5.0.1.1 will not install on a RPi1 running Raspbian jessie.
There are missing command files used in the install scripts. You need to return to mono v3.2.12.

It installs fine on the RPi 3 installs of Raspbian jessie from the same image.